# How to specify key for kafka producer in apache nifi?

Tags: json, apache-kafka, apache-nifi

I have simple pipeline using apache nifi and i want to publish some messages in kafka topic using existing kafka puplisher processor.
[image]

The problem is how to specify kafka key using apache nifi expression language?
I tired something like `${message:jsonPath('$.key')}` but, of course, i got an error because object `message` does not exist.
[image]

I also tried to use `filename` object which is something like a default object name for input messages, but it didn't help

---

Using another kafka publisher processor it is possible by setting `message key field` property, but what about `PublishKafka` processor?

Comment: Share the error details. `Kafka Key` supports EL evaluation so if you use a valid EL, it should ideally work.

Comment: @SivaprasannaSethuraman, the problem that i specified not existing object, because i didn't know which object reference i should use for it. Now i got the idea how to solve it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NiFi expression language can only reference flow file attributes, and cannot directly reference the content (this is done on purpose).

So if you want to use the value of a field from your json document as the key, then you need to first use another processor like EvaluateJsonPath to extract the value of that field into a flow file attribute.

Lets say you have a field "foo" in your json document, you might use EvaluateJsonPath with destination to set to "flow file attributes" and then add a dynamic property like:

foo = $.foo

Then in PublishKafka set the key property to ${foo}.

Keep in mind this only makes sense if you have a single json document per flow file, otherwise if you have multiple then it is unclear what the key is since you can only have one "foo" attribute for the flow file, but many "foo" fields in the content of the flow file.

Comment: Does it mean that the key should be String type? Let's say we need to publish a record that Key is Long and value is Object, how to convert Key to the Long type if attributes cannot be any other type except String?